Generate Schema with Custom ValidationAttribute
I want to generate a json schema of an object using a custom ValidationAttribute which is defined as:
public class CustomMaxLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const int DefaultMaxLength = 30;

    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var maxLength = DefaultMaxLength;
        if (validationContext.ObjectType == typeof(Document))
        {
            maxLength = 63;
        }

        var length = 0;
        
        switch (value)
        {
            case null:
                return new ValidationResult($"Invalid {validationContext.MemberName}");
            case string str:
                length = str.Length;
                break;
        }

        if (length <= maxLength)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult($"Invalid {validationContext.MemberName}");
        }
    }

Now I have a base class, where this attribute is added into
public class ResourceTypeBase
{
    [CustomMaxLength]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

This subclass is :
public class Document: ResourceTypeBase
{
    
}

i want to generate schema for the object Document, so that I get the response as
"properties": {
        "Name": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 63
        }
      }


Currently it is coming blank and it does not even recognise my Custom Validation Attribute.
"properties": {
        "Name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }

What should I do ?
